# Using generic named type in API Blueprint on Apiary.io

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io

How can I use [generic named type](https://github.com/apiaryio/mson/blob/master/MSON%20Specification.md#53-generic-named-type) in my API Blueprint definition?

I try like this:

```
FORMAT: 1A HOST: http://test.com/

# API Blueprint testing.

## Resource [/resources]
### Action [GET]

+ Response 200 (application/json)

    + Attributes
        + decorated_person (Address Decorator(Person))


# Data Structures

## Person (object)
+ first_name
+ last_name

## Address Decorator (*T*)
+ address
```

But Apiary Editor give me the error:

> base type 'Address Decorator(Person)' is not defined in the document

Answer (score 0):

here is two problems. Address Decorator isn't base type for example object and in attributes you have to use [Mixin](https://github.com/apiaryio/mson/blob/master/MSON%20Specification.md#51-mixin-type) or [Nesting](https://github.com/apiaryio/mson/blob/master/MSON%20Specification.md#43-nested-member-types).

```
FORMAT: 1A 

HOST: http://test.com/

# API Blueprint testing.

## Resource [/resources]
### Action [GET]

+ Response 200 (application/json)

    + Attributes
        + Include AddressDecorator


# Data Structures

## Person (object)
+ first_name
+ last_name

## AddressDecorator (object)
+ address
```

Comment: Ladislav, thanks for answer, but I want to know how can I use generic named types in API Blueprint definition. Rather than how can I workaround it.